# API requests are not being called from frontend

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to write front-end api requests for a simple project of mine.

```
const [beerData, setBeerData] = useState<Record<string, Beer>>({});
const [personData, setPersonData] = useState<Record<string, Person>>({});

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    setBeerData(await getBeersData());
    setPersonData(await getPersonsData());
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

```
async function getPersonsData(): Promise<Record<string, Person>> {
    console.log("persopn");
    try {
        console.log(1);
        const response = await axios.get(`${server_path}${api_path}/person`);
        console.log(2);
        return response.data as Record<string, Person>;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error.message);
        return {};
    }
}

async function getBeersData(): Promise<Record<string, Beer>> {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${server_path}${api_path}/beer`);
        return response.data as Record<string, Beer>;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error.message);
        return {};
    }
}
```

The problem is I have data on my server, the API is working, none of my console logs are being displayed and the data on the client side is empty.

Any ideas on what the issue might be?
Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

I figured out the requests were hanging because of CORS.
I added the following settings to my vite configuration file:

```
    server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4999/',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    }
  },
```

The requests are still hanging. I setup cors by just doing `app.use(cors)`

Answer (score 0):

there's bit missing from you sample to consider.

start by refactoring the await calls to variables and check that they log anything

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const beersResponse = await getBeersData()
    console.log('what was returned?', beersResponse)

    setBeerData(beersResponse);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

you may also need to run a json.parse() / response.json() on the response before returning from the apiClient.

if you're getting logs it mean that get*data methods aren't executing.

you may also need to handle json data?

```
return response.json(); || return JSON.parse(response)
```

noting you've typed it as a string should it be a string or json data?

Comment: I edited the code with the stuff I have figured out.

Comment: nice, cors errors are always a little tricky to spot and resolve

Comment: I didn't solve it though, that's the issue :)

Comment: there's a lot of reasons for CORS errors you'll need to update your question with error details or make a new one. you'll need to consider api allowed origins, if https is requried by the api, that axios has no-cors mode set. We can't help you without an updated question.